# How to display picture in artifacts on CircleCI on Github Readme

Tags: github, circleci

My test suite outputs a lcov report and a badge that displays percent coverage. The badge is a png that's in the artifacts folder.

I try to embed the image as follows, but it only displays the alt text on my Github readme.md. The link is correct in that if I copy and paste it, the page takes me to the file I want.

Is the fact that the link is actually an api call the reason why I can't display the picture? If so, how can I do this? Below is my (editted) code:

```
![Statement Coverage](https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/myorg/myrepo/latest/artifacts/0/$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/coverage.png?branch=master&filter=successful&circle-token=mytoken)
```

It also doesn't work if I try and just use an `<img/>` tag in the readme.

Comment: I would try uploading your test coverage data to a service and then use their badge.

Comment: Hi Swagrov, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @balkoth No, the answer below is correct in that the markdown won't grab the picture from the link since it's an API call and not a link to the image. I ended up just not showing this badge at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you consider the [list of badges to include](https://gist.github.com/skratchdot/e44d7df7683a525f4b68) (like the ones exposed by [shields.io](https://shields.io/)), none of those URL involve an API call.

So if you can, try and reference a fixed URL instead of an API one.